# How to remap LMB => A-pause-LMB

Tags: autohotkey

I wanted to remap the wheel button to the left mouse button, which is "MButton::LButton" i think.

But then I wanted to remap the left mouse button to two keys, the "a" button then the left mouse button. Its for a game, so I think it has to have some minimal pause between them, but i cant remap them to be on the same time anyways.

Comment: so... what is the question; "how to remap LMB => LMB-pause-A"?

Comment: yes, but its actualy  LMB => A-pause-LMB,
a must be first

Comment: I think your question was downvoted because what you were asking wasn't clear.  If you rephrase your question to be easier to understand, I'll give you my vote.

Comment: thank you, i'm new to this site. I'll be more specific next time.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your question.  I gave you my vote.  Good luck with Stack Exchange - it's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map the Mouse Wheel button to the Left Mouse Button:

```
mbutton::lbutton
```

However, you CAN map one key to two keys (with a pause, too):

Consider this:

```
mbutton::
    send a
    sleep, 100
    send {lbutton}
return
```